# Android GridView adapter based that supports drag and drop of child views

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, drag-and-drop

I want to implement GridView that supports Adapter and allows drag and drop (reordering) of items. The important is that it needs to support Adapter because I saw some implementations over the Web that are based on static adding Views to GridView.